# postgresql join jsonb and condition

Tags: postgresql

my postgresql version is 14.9
there is a_table:

```
| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB)                                                           | state (JSONB)                        | 
| ---------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------------ | -------------------------------------|
| apple      | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "green" }]  | [{ "color": "green", "op2": "bad" }]|
| orange     | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "235", "color": "blue" }]  | [{ "color": "blue", "op2": "best" }] |
| lemon      | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }]  | [{ "color": "red", "op2": "good" }]  |
```

I want this select sql output :

```
| Name (Txt)   | Detail (JSONB)                           | state (JSONB)                      | 
| --------     | -----------------------------------------| -----------------------------------|
| apple        | { "code": "156", "color": "red"}         |                                    |
| apple        | { "code": "156", "color": "green"}       | { "color": "green", "op2": "bad" } |
| orange       | { "code": "156", "color": "red" }        |                                    |
| lemon        | { "code": "156", "color": "red" }        | { "color": "red", "op2": "good" }  |
| lemon        | { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }       |                                    |
```

I did try this sql :

```
 SELECT
        "Name (Txt)"
     ,  jsonb_build_object('code', elem->>'code', 'color', elem->>'color')  AS "Detail (JSONB)"
     ,  state::JSONB "
    FROM your_table,
         jsonb_array_elements("Detail (JSONB)") AS elem,
         state::JSONB
    WHERE elem->>'code' = '156';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL query, it chooses particular elements from JSONB arrays in the "Detail" and "state" columns and formats them in accordance with your request.

```
SELECT
    "Name (Txt)",
    jsonb_build_object('code', elem->>'code', 'color', elem->>'color') AS "Detail (JSONB)",
    CASE
        WHEN state::JSONB->>'color' = elem->>'color' THEN state::JSONB
        ELSE '{}'::JSONB
    END AS "state (JSONB)"
FROM your_table
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements("Detail (JSONB)") AS elem
WHERE elem->>'code' = '156'
OR (elem->>'code' = '235' AND elem->>'color' = 'blue');
```

hope it works :)